# Error retrieving user id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, mongoose

My app basically lets you put a link of a photo and detects the face of the person. 
So here's the deal, I am developing it with MERN and everything is working but this part:

```
app.put('/image', (req, res) => {
 const { id } = req.body;

User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$inc : { 'entries': 1}})
console.log(id);
     .then(user => {
         return res.json(user.entries);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).json('Error getting entries');
        console.log(err);
    })      
});
```

When a console.log it, it basically says that 'id' therefore 'user' is undefined. When I try on Postman sending an ID directly,  it works fine, but I can't think of why it's returning undefined. I am guessing it's something on the Frontend is not getting the ID of the user and sending to the backend.

That's the onSubmit Function:

```
    onButtonSubmit = () => {
  this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input});
    app.models
      .predict(
        Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, 
        this.state.input)
    .then(response => {
      if (response) {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/image', {
            method: 'put',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
        id: this.state.user.id
            })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(count => {
        this.setState(this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, {entries: count})))
      })
    } 
    this.displayFaceBox(this.calculateFaceLocation(response))
    })
}
```

And that's the Rank component where it's supposed to show how many entries one has.

```
const Rank = ({ name, entries }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className='f3'>
                {`${name} , your current entry count is...`}
            </div>
            <div className='white f1'>
                {entries}
            </div>
        </div>
        );
};
```

If anyone could help me it'd be great!

Comment: Is `http://localhost:3000` a different origin? Look at the Network tab in the Developer Tools of your browser. There might be a CORS error.

Comment: Are you sure there's an actual user with an ID in state before you make your request? And probably unrelated, but after the request is made, you have a setState within a setState (`this.setState(this.setState(...))`)

Comment: Check what you get if you do a console.log(this.state.user.id) inside your onButtonSubmit() function. Why are you stringifying the object in the body key?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I found the problem and addressed it. I also fixed the this.setState problem .

Answer (score 0):

If the request is going through the error should be that you are converting the object to a string client side and forgetting to parse it server side.

```
body: JSON.stringify({
           id: this.state.user.id
})
```

Server side you should parse the body to convert it back to an object

`const data = JSON.parse(req.body)
const id = data.id`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Turns out it was the function loadUser (which I didn't post here).  I forgot to change `id: user.id` for `id: user._id`

Thanks a lot!